# Documentation examples require relevant struct to be imported, but only when running tests. Is this intended behavior?

Tags: rust

I have a very simple struct and a `new()` implementation for said struct.

````
    pub struct Square {
        rank: usize,
        file: usize,
    }

    impl Square {
        /// # Examples
        /// ```
        /// Square::new(0,0); //The square A1.
        /// ```
    }
````

In addition, I have some tests (these tests do call `Square::new()`, though they aren't tests for that function). When I run `cargo test`, I get the following error for the code in my documentation example:

> use of undeclared type `Square`.
> Consider importing this struct.

Curiously, this problem doesn't happen when I run `cargo build` or `cargo doc`.

The problem goes away when I import the struct as the compiler recommends. However, it doesn't seem like this is something I should have to do, since (I presume) examples should be as concise as possible. Looking at the [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#448) for `String::new()`, the example documentation consists of one line of code, no imports needed. The [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/env.rs.html#788-790) for `env::args` does include an import of `std::env`, though.

Is this intended behavior? Is this a bug?

Comment: Parts of examples can be hidden from viewing in rustdoc output py prefixing the line with a `#`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behavior. [Doctests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/documentation-tests.html) are a powerful tool to both document your API and test your implementation at the same time. To do that they must compile successfully.

However, being documentation, doctests also need to be short and concise. So if you believe some code isn't required to understand the example (but is still required to be there in order for the doctest to compile), you can hide this line by prepending a `#` to it:

````rust
/// # Examples
/// ```
/// # use crate::Square;
/// Square::new(0,0); //The square A1.
/// ```
````